# TP-Link Omada Controller - Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Tags: linux, java, raspberry-pi

I have small problem. Today I'm trying to setup Omada Controller (same as UniFi Controller) on my RaspBerry Pi 3. Everything looks good, but when I'm trying to start the controller, it shows this error - "Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr/lib/jvm/default-java." I'm trying to fix it, but without success. I have installed all versions of java, but it doesn't help. Any options, how to fixit easily? In the description below is a screenshot, wiht error. Thanks for any help. [k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF8Jz.png)

I was installing with this manual - https://dreambyte.nl/2018/12/27/installing-eap-controller-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 7):

My case:  Mint (ubuntu 20.04) with java-11 family
The paths etc above installed correctly and the above fixes did not help/were not needed.

Thanks to JARVIS at https://www.taste-of-it.de/tp-link-omada-controller-install-java-home-error/

```
# mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64
# ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/
```

and that fixed it.  I'm not expert enough to have found where those rogue paths are being used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated guide for the latest version 3.2.1

https://blog.jeffery.net.nz/2019/10/omada-controller-on-raspbian.html

More or less you need to check your Java install and make sure the symbolic link to the Java home is correct:

```
apt-get install jsvc
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
cd /usr/lib/jvm
ln -s java-8-openjdk-armhf default-java
tpeap start
```

If you still have issues then follow each step again from the guide.

Comment: these lines from the manual are very important: sed -i -e 's/JRE_HOME="${OMADA_HOME}\/jre"/JRE_HOME="\/usr\/lib\/jvm\/default-java"/g' Omada_Controller_v3.2.1_linux_x64/bin/control.sh
sed -i -e 's/JAVA_OPTS="-server/JAVA_OPTS="-client/g' Omada_Controller_v3.2.1_linux_x64/bin/control.sh

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20, with Omada 5.7.4. Thanks!